# Trying to print AGENTID,name and NUMBEROFSALES

Tags: sql

```
SELECT AGENTID, NAME 
FROM SALESAGENT 
WHERE = (SELECT AGENTID, COUNT (AGENTID) AS NUMBEROFSALES 
         FROM SALESTRANSACTION
         GROUP BY AGENTID
         ORDER BY NUMBEROFSALES DESC);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn’t very clear.
I’m assuming you have a lookup table SALESAGENT which has the agent names and agentID and a SalesTransaction table which has individual Sales data associated with agentIDs.

```
Select agent.agent_id, agent.name, count(agent.agent_id) as numberofsales
from salesagent as agent
inner join salestransaction as sales
on agent.agent_id = sales.agent_id
group by agent.agent_id
order by count(agent.agent_id) desc
```